# Spring Boot 3 native image fails with there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I've upgraded a quite complex Spring Boot application to Boot 3.0 and Cloud 2022.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

These are the defined dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro") version "1.5.0"
    jacoco
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.21"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.19"
}

java.sourceCompatibility = VERSION_17

repositories {
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://packages.confluent.io/maven") }
    maven { url = uri("https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local") }

}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2022.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
extra["confluentVersion"] = "7.3.0"
extra["avroVersion"] = "1.11.1"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave")
    implementation("io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:${property("confluentVersion")}")
    implementation("io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:${property("confluentVersion")}")
    implementation("io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:${property("confluentVersion")}")
    implementation("org.apache.avro:avro:${property("avroVersion")}")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("javax.money:money-api:1.1")
    implementation("org.javamoney:moneta:1.4.2")
    implementation("com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark:0.17.0")
```

I've generated the native image using:

```
./gradlew clean  bootBuildImage
```

The image is started specifying a couple of profiles:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local,confluent-cloud docker.io/library/myapp:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

It fails with `Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.`.

```
2022-12-15T20:12:25.981Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [           main] i.s.m.MyAppKt      : Starting AOT-processed MyAppKt using Java 17.0.5 with PID 1 (/workspace/i.s.m.MyAppKt started by cnb in /workspace)
2022-12-15T20:12:25.981Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [           main] i.s.m.MyAppKt      : The following 2 profiles are active: "local", "confluent-cloud"
2022-12-15T20:12:25.985Z  WARN [,,] 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2022-12-15T20:12:25.985Z ERROR [,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Are those all your dependencies? Have you tried `SPRING_PROFILES_INCLUDE` instead of `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`? The latter will disable the `default` profile, the first will add to it.

Comment: Yes, those are all the dependencies. Same error using `SPRING_PROFILES_INCLUDE`.

Comment: Try to enable debugging probably by passing DEBUG=true to docker. Check your dependencies to see if no unsupported classes are in your classpath. Finally as you are using a native image make sure everything is in there. I would expect yu would need to pass in the active profiles during native image building as well as to make sure all the paths are being detected, if you don't stuff might be left out.

Comment: I tried adding `spring.profiles.active=local,confluent-cloud`at application.yml and still get the same error.

Comment: I also unified all properties removing the profiles with the same result.

Comment: You don't have any profiles left? Please post your `build.gradle` file, there must be something in there that messes things up, or in your own configuration.

Comment: The problem is the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency. When I removed it that error didn't show up again.

Comment: by removing ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap```  it works , but could not find the root cause.